# UIScrollView displacement

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my IB I have a navigation controller which has in it a view controller.

When I am trying to load this view controller from another navigation controller the scroll view is being displaced by the size of a navigation bar to the bottom. All other elements of my view are not moving except the scroll view.

Why does it happen and how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Size tab of the IB Inspector palette, ensure your scroll view has its autoresizing behaviour set to such:

[image]

Likewise, ensure the scroll view's super view is set with the same autoresizing behaviour.